# C# Web Cam with Remoting

Tags: webcam, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

My project is about Remoting and i want to add a webcam component to it. Here it goes: I have 3 project in my solution... Client, Server, Remote.dll. In Remote.dll is a common class which has methods works in server machine. When i call these methods from Client it executes in server side. So now my question is i put the code of Webcam in remote.dll and it has an event called "video_NewFrame" which it works everytime when webcam catch an image. But i cant reach to the images from my Client side because when code drops to this event it executes infinitely
and my timer in Client side doesnt work as well. I tried to assing image to my global variable but whenever code goes to client and comes to Remote.dll again my variable is null...
How can i reach simultaneously captured images from my client? here is my code: 
(i use AForge framework for webcam)

```
    private bool DeviceExist = true;
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;

    public bool WebCamStart(int DeviceIndex)
    {
        if (DeviceExist)
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            //string myDevice = videoDevices[0].Name;
            videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

            CloseVideoSource();
            videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(640, 480);
            //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
            videoSource.Start();
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public Bitmap lastImg;

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        //in executes infinitely when execution comes here and i cant reach from Cliend side...
    }


    public string getFPS()
    {
        return videoSource.FramesReceived.ToString();
    }

    public void CloseVideoSource()
    {
        if (!(videoSource == null))
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource.Stop();
                videoSource = null;
            }
    }

    public string getCamList()
    {
        string result = "No Device Found";
        try
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException();

            DeviceExist = true;
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                //comboBox1.Items.Add(device.Name);
                result = device.Name;
                return result;
            }
            //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //make dafault to first cam
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            DeviceExist = false;
            //comboBox1.Items.Add("No capture device on your system");
            return "No capture device on your system";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

// and my client side...

```
    private void timerWebCam_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lblFPS.Text ="Device Running... " + remObj.getFPS() + " FPS";
        pictureBox1.Image = remObj.lastImg;
    }
```